# Embedded array insert in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, insert

For practice purposes, I have 3 users which I have inserted into my database.

JSON code:

```
[
    {
    "f_name": "Raf", 
    "l_name":"Bak", 
    "age": 19, 
    },
    {
    "f_name":"miltos",
    "l_name":"Bak", 
    "age": 56,
    },
    {
    "f_name":"eleni",
    "l_name":"kot", 
    "age": 27,
    }
]
```

I want to insert for every user a history array and within that array another array. I use the following JSON code but I get an error.

```
db.patientdata.insertOne({f_name:"Raf"},{$set: {history:["desease":"fever","treatment":"ponstan"]}})
```

[image]

Do I have to "$set" the 2nd array as well?

Thank you in advance.

**edit after further meddling with this:**

I also tired the following JSON code:

```
db.patientdata.updateOne({f_name:"Raf"},{$set: {"history":["desease","treatment"]}})
db.patientdata.updateOne({f_name:"Raf"},{$set: {"desease":["fever"]}})
db.patientdata.updateOne({f_name:"Raf"},{$set: {"treatment":["ponstan"]}})
```

but I there wasn't a second embedded array within the first one:
[image]

Comment: why not this? `db.patientdata.updateOne({f_name:"Raf"},{$set: {history:[{disease:"doesn't know good programming",treatment: "study more"}]}})` i think its ok, if you want to update the existing one

Comment: Yes, thank you Takis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted a new user from the beginning and it works fine.

JSON code:

```
db.patientdata.insert({f_name:"George",l_name:"Bak","age":29, history:[{disease:"doesn't know good programming",treatment: "study more"}]})
```

[image: when I searched for the results]

Comment: Can you [edit] this to include the JSON as text and format using Markdown, instead of pasting it as an image? Thank you.